# Who was the trinket seller?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

In the fourth episode of the fourth season, Faustus Blackwood finds the fourth eldritch terror in the possession of a trinket seller. This terror is known as the Imp of the Perverse, and Faustus takes it from the trinket seller, tossing him out into the street.

This whole interchange is unusual in several aspects. First, virtually all the terrors came to Greendale,  if not directly to Faustus, of their own accord, but the Perverse was brought by someone else, and there is no indication that Faustus arranged this meeting any more than he did with the other terrors. Further, the person who brought it seemed to have no interest in giving the Perverse to Faustus, so it is curious that they went to his church and sought to sell him trinkets in the first place. Second, they had not only the Perverse but many other extrremely powerful magical artifacts in their possession, which is unusual in itself, yet they were selling them instead of using their vast powers for their own gain.

Finally, the seller gave Ambrose the Stone of Omphalos, another powerful artifact, for absolutely nothing, calling into question both their monetary motivations and basically eliminating any possiblity that they were an acolyte of the terrors bent on bringing them to Earth. Not to mention that they came by again and traded something very useful to Sabrina in exchange for the Imp.

So who was the trinket seller and what did they truly desire?